# How to get date using year and week in PHP?

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
$gendate = new DateTime();

$gendate->setISODate(2014,52,4);

echo $gendate->format('d-m-Y');
```

I want to code in core PHP because i am new in PHP. I hope you will get it what i want?

Comment: add 4 spaces before code to highlight it

Comment: are you asking for this ????????
date('Y-m-d'); 
This will display current date in YYYY-MM-DD format..

Comment: What date do you want if you only have year and week? Any day of the week? The first day? Last day?

Comment: It's better to google at least for one time.

Comment: indeed, you need to specify what exactly your desired output is

Comment: I have week and year but i want date from any week in CORE PHP only

Comment: Get what date? The monday? The sunday? The start day? The end day? The wendesday? What does 4 mean? Is that the day starting from sunday? Starting from monday? We really need more info.

Comment: I get output is : 25-12-2014 but i want code in CORE PHP only

Comment: `DateTime` **is** core PHP as long as you use `5.2.0+` (a version that was released in **2006** and stopped support in **2011**). Essentially, `DateTime` has been a part of PHP for 9 years. I think you'd be OK using it.

Answer (score 0):

when i understand you right

try this

```
  $time = strtotime("1 January $year", time());
  $day = date('w', $time);
  $time += ((7*$week)+1-$day)*24*3600;
  $dates[0] = date('Y-n-j', $time);
  $time += 6*24*3600;
  $dates[1] = date('Y-n-j', $time);
  var_dump($dates);
```

Comment: Thanks to all whom give me some ideas